# python 3.5 windows не поддерживает junction point

Tags: windows, python-3.5

Для копирования симлинки используется следующий код

```
 if os.path.islink(src_path):
       linkto = os.readlink(src_path)
       os.symlink(linkto, dest_path)
```

однако os.path.islink и os.readlink не умеют работать с junction point

Как распознать junction point и пересоздать его в другом месте?

Comment: islink и readlink это разные функции—поправьте заголовок (очевидно, что [islink() не всегда False--запустите `test-symlink.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/a1d11b20eecdf82719b13df651ae99a0)). В сторону: не обязательно `ctypes` здесь использовать: (`os.lstat(filename).st_file_attributes & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT`).

Comment: После запуска скрипта и получения OSError: symbolic link privilege not held и немногих проверок понял, что python видит ссылки созданные через mklink /D (требуют админ привилегий кстати), но не понимает "junction" созданные через mklink /j, хотя я не вижу разницы в поведении созданных "ссылок"

Comment: поэтому текст скрипта и содержит: "requires SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege" напротив `os.symlink()`—проще как администратор запустить, конечно. Существует три понятия: symbolic links, junction points, mount points под зонтиком reparse points. То есть  junction отличается от symlink и наличия `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` не достаточно: `not islink()` (на уровне win32 отличаются `dwReserved0`: `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` vs. `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`). stdlib по разному сейчас к junction относится: в одном месте это директория rmdir(path), в другом ссылка unlink().

Comment: со временем можно ожидать, что на уровне Питона, junction всё больше как symlink на других системах будут себя вести. Например, [сейчас `os.walk(root, follow_symlinks=False)` всё равно переходит по junction, но это может измениться](http://bugs.python.org/issue23407)

Comment: [как islink() так и readlink() могут начать работать не только для symlink, но и для junction (точно не ясно пока)](http://bugs.python.org/review/23407/diff/18660/Lib/test/test_os.py)

Comment: Я ни разу не испытывал проблем с junction ни в одной программе, в том числе и на питоне - видимо все доверяют это дело нижележащему уровню оси и поэтому везде работает. Тогда вопрос сводится к следующему "как быть если я пишу функцию переноса/слияния каталогов (ибо shutil.move бесполезен), а внутри могут быть как симлинки так и junction (на уровне винды их визуально не отличить) и что мне сейчас делать с junction при  текущей имплементации питона, если я просто хочу перенести ее как симлинку?"

Comment: я вам явно привёл ссылку на баг в os.walk()—по меньшей мере для кого-то текущее поведение не является ожидаемым. *"просто перенести ее как симлинку"*: задайте отдельный вопрос и подробно опишите желаемое поведение (очевидное для вас): к примеру хотите ли вы чтобы junction подчинялись бы follow_symlinks параметру? Хотите ли все junction на настоящие symlink заменить (прав требует) или как папки скопировать? Чем конкретно shutil.move() не устраивает? Что этот вызов сейчас делает? Что бы вы хотели чтобы он делал (создавал папку/junction/symlink?). Есть ли сетевые папки или всё локально?

Comment: @jfs переписал полностью вопрос. по факту имплементирую перемещение папки со слиянием  (с вложенными папками, симлинками и так далее ) раз уж готового питон не предоставляет. Сетевые папки под вопросом - я и более базовую вещь написать не могу.

Comment: 1- в чём у вас вопрос? как реализовать rsync кросс-платформенный? (это слишком большая задача). Попробуйте более специфичный вопрос, например: "os.path.islink не распознает junction point на Питоне 3.5 Windows 7. Как реализовать isjunction()?"  (ваша проверка, используя FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT неверна, как я уже выше сказал). Не нужно говорить "нашёл на SO" без конкретной ссылки (SO старается отношение сигнал/мусор повысить, но всё равно ошибочной информации навалом--или даже верный ответ в вашем контексте может быть неприменим).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47927/discussion-between-jfs-and-vitidev).

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972776/having-trouble-implementing-a-readlink-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Python 3.5, `os.path.islink()`, `os.readlink()`, `os.symlink()` работают только с символьными ссылками [*как и задокументировано*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink). NTFS символьные ссылки (на файлы/папки), моделирующие Unix symlinks, доступны пользовательским приложениям, [начиная с Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680(v=vs.85).aspx).

NTFS junctions это близкое (ссылки на директории) но [отличающееся понятие (привилегии, удалённые пути)](https://superuser.com/q/343074/13868), поддерживаемое [с Windows 2000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205524), хотя фактическое создание/удаление Junction требовало там установки дополнительных утилит и [стандартные утилиты, типа создания резервного копирования, могли ломаться на папках, содержащих junctions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/973455). Благодаря изменению имён стандартных папок между разными версиями Винды и [использованию junction points для поддержки обратной совместимости](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829(v=vs.85).aspx), Junction достаточно распространены сейчас (выполните `DIR /AL /S` в cmd, чтобы увидеть примеры).

C точки зрения многих приложений, Junction это обычная папка. В контексте резервного копирования, чтобы избежать зацикливания или копирования одних и тех же файлов несколько раз, к junction points следует относится похоже как к символическим ссылкам на других системах.

Как символические ссылки так и Junction реализованы как reparse points, поэтому код в вопросе, когда они указывают на директории, можно заменить на (не тестировано):

```py
if is_reparse_point(src_path): # symlinkd, junction, etc
   try:
       linkto = os.readlink(src_path)
   except ValueError: # not a symlink
       linkto = readlink(src_path) # junction, mount point
       create_junction(linkto, dest_path)
   else:
       os.symlink(linkto, dest_path, target_is_directory=True)
```

где возможные реализации функций, поддерживающие junction points:

```py
import errno
import os
import stat
from tkinter import Tcl

from _winapi import CreateJunction as create_junction

def is_reparse_point(path):
    try: #              | stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        return bool(os.lstat(path).st_file_attributes
                    & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT) 
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno not in (errno.ENOENT, errno.ENOTDIR):
            raise
        return False  # path doesn't exist

def readlink(path):
    assert '"' not in path
    return Tcl().eval('file readlink "%s"' % path.replace('\\', '\\\\'))
```

где:

- `create_junction()` это аналог [mklink /J](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)
- `is_reparse_point()` может вернуть `True` не только для Junction, но и символической ссылки, [mount point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363940(v=vs.85).aspx) ([`os.path.ismount()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.ismount)) и (возможно) [других объектов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365511(v=vs.85).aspx).

  Формально, символическая ссылка это `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` с `WIN32_FIND_DATA.dwReserved0` равным `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`, а junction это `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT`, которая не [mount point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363940(v=vs.85).aspx)
- `readlink()` возвращает путь к папке куда Junction указывает (как `os.readlink()` для symlink). Для простоты, используется tcl, чтобы этот путь получить, иначе возможна [реализация, использующая `ctypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979160/4279):

  ```py
  >>> readlink(r'C:\Documents and Settings')
  'C:\\Users'
  ```

Альтернативно, существуют PyPI модули разной степени полировки и применимости в зависимости от конкретного случая, к примеру [`ntfsutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntfsutils), [`jaraco.windows`](https://github.com/jaraco/jaraco.windows/blob/ba0316c609fb304ef81255f0a63c03ed9c15e241/jaraco/windows/filesystem/__init__.py#L66), предоставляющие похожую функциональность. В будущем, [возможно `os.path.islink()` и `os.readlink()` станут поддерживать напрямую и Directory Junction](http://bugs.python.org/review/23407/diff/18660/Lib/test/test_os.py).

Comment: Вот еще вопрос с англоязычного SO, где приводится рабочий код, работающий с симлинками и junction одинаково хорошо http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972776/having-trouble-implementing-a-readlink-function

Comment: @TheGodfather: мой ответ *уже* содержит ссылку на ответ из этого вопроса.