# Symlink: как узнать target?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Как узнать **target** "symlink" (узнать где сам файл находится)?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [о работе с различными видами reparse point (e.g., junction) на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/586134/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Temp>mklink /d sym aaa\bbb
symbolic link created for sym <<===>> aaa\bbb
```

Нижеприведенный код работает для Python **3.x** под Windows:

```
In [25]: p = r'c:/temp/sym'

In [26]: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(p), os.readlink(p)))
Out[26]: 'c:\\temp\\aaa\\bbb'
```

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.readlink):

> **os.readlink(path)**
>
> Return a string representing the path to which the symbolic link points. The result may be either an absolute or
>   relative pathname; if it is relative, it may be converted to an
>   absolute pathname using `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), result)`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'readlink'

Comment: @myvvar, какой у вас дистрибутив и какая версия Python?

Comment: python-2.7.3.amd64

Comment: @myvvar, пардон! Этот метод работает под Windows только для Python 3.x

Comment: Я по этому и добавил тэг "python-2.7".

Comment: @myvvar, единственное что я смог найти для Python 2.x под Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924557/5741205