# Как с помощью python сделать модуль для c++

Tags: c++, python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Как с помощью python 3.6.1 сделать модуль для c++
То-есть написать на python какой-то модуль, что-то с ним сделать и запускать через c++, допустим  `print("Hello, world")` и когда мы импортируем эту библиотеку в c++ то будет выводить Hello,  world

Comment: Хотелось бы чуть больше конкретики: вы хотите из Сишной программы вызывать питоний скрипт?

Comment: о_О `file = open('mdl.cpp'); file.write('#include <iostream>\n');` ... и так далее. Если это не ответ на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, переформулируйте вопрос

Comment: Думаю [это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value) должно подойти. [Оригинальная](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) статья.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете Питон-код как внешнюю команду вызвать. К примеру:

```c++
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
   return system("python -mwebbrowser http://example.com");
}
```

---

Чтобы выполнить Питон-код в С++, [можно встроить (embed) Python-интерпретатор](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html):

```c++
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('hello world')");
  return Py_FinalizeEx() < 0;
}
```

Чтобы собрать программу, можно `Makefile` использовать:

```c++
NAME := embed-python-interpreter
PYTHON_VERSION := python-3.6

$(NAME): $(NAME).cc
    $(CXX) `pkg-config --cflags ${PYTHON_VERSION}` $< -o $@ `pkg-config --libs ${PYTHON_VERSION}`
```

Также можно встраивать Питон, используя [cffi](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html), [cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Demos/embed).

---

Можно скомпилировать подмножество кода на Питоне в Си. К примеру, [используя Pypy `translate.py` программу](https://github.com/zed/loop-modulo-benchmark/blob/master/primes_below-c.do), которая умеет RPython в Си транслировать.

---

Обычно, наоборот C/C++ код используется, чтобы расширение для Питона создать или напрямую с помощью ctypes, cffi Си код вызывается из Питона:

```c++
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
>>> libc.printf(b"abc\n")
abc
4
```

Здесь вызывается `printf()` Си функция из libc, включённой в CPython интерпретатор. `abc` это вывод в C stdout. `4` это Python REPL печатает возвращаемое значение из `printf()` (4 байта напечатано). Вот более сложные примеры:

- вызов [`clock_gettime()` Си функции из `<time.h>` (`-lrt`) на Linux](https://gist.github.com/zed/5073409)
- вызов [`FindFirstFileW()` из kernel32 на Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979160/4279), чтобы реализовать [аналог os.path.islink(), который junctions поддерживает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/586134/23044).

Вот [пример использования OpenSSL API, чтобы из x509 сертификата серийный номер достать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574662/23044) который показывает, что при вызове многих функций, удобней более высокоуровневыми библиотеками пользоваться нежели напрямую `ctypes`.

[Cython](http://cython.org/) удобен, чтобы интегрировать С/C++ код с Питоном или заметно ускорить Питон код. [`clipped_cumsum()`, реализованная в Cython](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583392/23044), в 100 раз быстрее аналога на чистом Питоне и иногда даже на порядок быстрее реализаций с помощью numpy, pandas, примеры: [`rotT()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4973390/4279), [`max_rolling_sum()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/733866/23044). Cython позволяет отпускать GIL, поэтому возможно ускорить чистые вычисления с помощью нескольких потоков, пример: [`b2a_bin()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/3526111#file-b2a_bin-pyx-L7). Cython можно встретить в исходниках популярных библиотек таких как `lxml`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, `scikit-learn`.