# Поиск подпоследовательности заданной длины в массиве с максимальной суммой

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Пусть есть массив чисел `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 0, 2]`.

Нужно найти последовательность из *трёх* (например) чисел, *сумма которых будет максимальна*.

Интересует *алгоритмически эффективный способ без переборов*, если такой есть, потому что нужно использовать на *очень больших массивах*. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Для каждых трех чисел хранить сумму второго и третьего и использовать при смещении области суммирования как готовое слагаемое? Выигрыш в 25% сразу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только для целей сравнения производительности (по [просьбе @MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733866/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9/734820#comment1118244_734086), иначе [их ответ вполне рабочий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733873/23044)), прямолинейный вариант на Cython на порядок быстрее `s.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum().idxmax()` решения:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'import numpy as np; a = np.random.randint(10**4, size=10**6); from max_rolling_sum import max_rolling_sum as f' 'f(a, 3)'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.7 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'import numpy as np; a = np.random.randint(10**4, size=10**6); from max_rolling_maxu import max_rolling_sum as f' 'f(a, 3)'
10 loops, best of 3: 48.1 msec per loop
```

где `max_rolling_sum.pyx`:

```
#cython: boundscheck=False

ctypedef long array_type

cpdef Py_ssize_t max_rolling_sum(array_type[:] arr, Py_ssize_t k) nogil:
    """arr[i:i+k].sum() is maximum."""
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = arr.shape[0]
    if N < 1:
        return -1  # error: no sum

    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef array_type sum_ = 0
    for i in range(min(k, N)):  # find first sum arr[:k].sum()
        sum_ += arr[i]
    cdef Py_ssize_t max_start = 0
    cdef array_type max_sum = sum_
    for i in range(k, N):   # compute rolling sum arr[i-k+1:i+1].sum()
        sum_ -= arr[i - k]  # pop (left) from old sum
        sum_ += arr[i]      # append (right) to new sum
        if max_sum < sum_:
            max_sum = sum_
            max_start = i - k + 1
    return max_start
```

а `max_rolling_maxu.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

def max_rolling_sum(arr, k):
    """arr[i:i+k].sum() is maximum."""
    s = pd.Series(arr)
    idx = s.rolling(k, min_periods=1).sum().idxmax()
    return max(idx - 2, 0)
```

Comment: здОрово, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно за O(n) времени и O(1) памяти при цикле, который будет хранить текущее максимальное и на каждой итерации надо будет вычислить сумму текущей подпоследовательности и сравнить с хранимой. При использовании "скользящего окна" тратится O(n) памяти.

Comment: Было бы интересно и полезно для других взглянуть на реализацию и сравнить скорость работы... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU: добавил [сравнение по вашей просьбе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/734820/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием Pandas:

Source Series:

```
import pandas as pd

In [109]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,6,3,4,0,2])

In [110]: s
Out[110]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    6
5    3
6    4
7    0
8    2
dtype: int64
```

Воспользуемся скользящим окном ([Series.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html)):

```
In [111]: s.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()
Out[111]:
0     1.0
1     3.0
2     6.0
3     9.0
4    13.0
5    13.0
6    13.0
7     7.0
8     6.0
dtype: float64

In [112]: idx = s.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum().idxmax()

In [113]: idx
Out[113]: 4

In [114]: s.loc[idx-2:idx]
Out[114]:
2    3
3    4
4    6
dtype: int64
```

Замер скорости для массива из 1.000.000 элементов:

```
In [18]: a = np.random.randint(10**4, size=10**6)

In [19]: a
Out[19]: array([9918, 4299, 7829, ..., 7513, 3367, 7140])

In [20]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 15

In [21]: s = pd.Series(a)

In [22]: %%timeit
    ...: idx = s.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum().idxmax()
    ...: s.loc[idx-2:idx]
    ...:
115 ms ± 7.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [23]: s.shape
Out[23]: (1000000,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто брать максимальные элементы. Можно отсортировать - O(n log n), а можно построить двоичную кучу и извлечь несколько максимумов - O(n + k log n).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ @jfs демонстрирует фактически общий подход к получению свертки с последовательностью единиц: крайнее число вычитаем, новое прибавляем. То есть, в нем как раз предоставлен алгоритм, который вам нужен, в то время как в ответе, выбранном лучшим, этот алгоритм скрыт в используемом модуле (если вообще этот).

Можно попытаться оптимизировать, но это сложная оптимизация. Фактически, последовательность единиц является характеристикой некоторого фильтра низкой частоты, а это накладывает ограничения на производные результата. То есть, если мы получили на данном шаге условно "маленькую" сумму при том, что уже имеем условно "большой" найденный максимум, то можно гарантировать, что на некотором количестве итераций нового максимума мы точно не получим, и пропустить эти итерации. Только при этом придется как-то пересчитать имеющуюся на данный момент сумму. Если это делать тем же алгоритмом, то оптимизиция всего лишь устраняет необходимость сравнения значения с максимумом на данном шаге, то есть мало что дает. Хотя, это зависит от природы исходного массива. Если они у вас очень большие и задача практическая, то, вероятно, это не случайные числа. Можно попытаться получать данные о характеристиках последовательности забегом вперед с некоторым шагом вместо 1. Но это сложные оптимизации при том, что способ из ответа @jfs сам по себе очень быстрый и требует всего 2 обращения к каждому элементу массива.