# Парсинг параметров URL в словарь

Tags: python, url

Интересно посмотреть на альтернативные реализации алгоритма, предложенного ниже.

---

При парсинге этого url (токен и id пользователя случайно-сгенерированные):

```
url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be2749' \
      '4b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146&expires_in=86400&' \
      'user_id=91585260'
params = url.split('#')[1].split('&')

token = {}
for i in params:
    x = i.split('=')
    token.update({x[0]: x[1]})

print(token)
```

Получаем:

```
{
    'access_token': 'f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be27494b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146', 
    'expires_in': '86400', 
    'user_id': '91585260'
}
```

Comment: Возможно вам подойдёт [urllib.parse.parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) он как раз извлекает параметры в виде ключ/значения в форме почти такой же как у вас. А так ваш алгоритм отлично выглядит, вроде в нём нечего улучшать.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul, спасибо за комментарий, но алгоритм можно улучшить, причем сделать в одну строку вместо 4, и почему бы вам не предложить ваше решение в виде ответа? :)

Comment: Все urllib обсудили, а чё ответа с ним никто так и не написал?)

Comment: @andreymal, я вот все жду когда кто-то выложит с ним ответ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [`urllib.parse` модуль из стандартной библиотеки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> fragment = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).fragment
>>> dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(fragment))
{'access_token': 'dea446c8...fa70d',
 'expires_in': '86400',
 'user_id': '28395070'}
```

Comment: А чем кроме использования urlparse ответ отличается? :) И нужно ли использовать urlparse, для получения из url фрагмента, если есть функция urldefrag? :)

Comment: @gil9red: мой ответ — это самое прямолинейное решение. Я удивился, что никто его не привёл. В вашем ответе, я увидел parse_qs(), предложенный @ Arty OneSoul, но проглядел `parse_qsl()`. `urldefrag()` я не помню когда пользовался -- ничего сказать не могу (для меня просто более очевидно, что *to parse url, use `urlparse()`*).

Answer (score 4):

У меня получилось вот так на C с конечным автоматом:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <longobject.h>

#define ST_URI 0
#define ST_KEY 1
#define ST_VALUE 2

static PyObject *
myurl_parse(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    char *c, *key = "", *value = "";
    int ksize = 0, vsize = 0, state = ST_URI;
    PyObject* result;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &c)) return NULL;

    result = PyDict_New();

    while (*c++) {
        if (*c == '#' && state == ST_URI) {
            state = ST_KEY;
            key = c+1;
        } else if (*c == '=' && state == ST_KEY) {
            state = ST_VALUE;
            ksize = c - key;
            value = c+1;
        } else if ( (*c == '&' || *c == 0) && state == ST_VALUE) {
            vsize = c - value;
            PyObject *ko = Py_BuildValue("s#", key, ksize);
            PyObject *vo = Py_BuildValue("s#", value, vsize);
            PyDict_SetItem(result, ko, vo);
            Py_DECREF(ko); Py_DECREF(vo);
            if (*c == '&') {
                state = ST_KEY;
                key = c+1;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

static PyMethodDef myurl_methods[] = {
    {"parse",  myurl_parse, METH_VARARGS, "The method parses URL."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef myurl_definition = { 
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "myurl",
    "My URL-parsing Python module.",
    -1, 
    myurl_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_myurl(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&myurl_definition);
}
```

Могут быть ошибки, но на вашем тесте работает:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
import myurl

url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be2749' \
      '4b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146&expires_in=86400&' \
      'user_id=91585260'

print(myurl.parse(url))
```

Результат:

```
{'user_id': '91585260', 'expires_in': '86400', 'access_token': 'f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be27494b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146'}
```

Самому интересно, почему словарь получился задом-наперед.

Comment: Ого, неожиданное решение на Cython'е :) Словарь там скорее всего построен на хешах, поэтому порядок у него может быть любой -- зависит от хеша

Comment: @gil9red, требует компиляции, зато должно работать быстро.

Comment: @gil9red: это не Cython (вот [пример кода на Cython](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/734820/23044)). Это C код, который использует CPython API. Причины, по которым здесь Си используются не ясны. Если ради производительности (если оказалось, что распознавание параметров ссылок это узкое место в вашем приложении), то следует явно сравнение указать. Если не в образовательных целях, то без явных причин лучше такой код не писать (сравните [Питон код и аналогичный Си код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716432/23044), который то же самое делает  через CPython API -- последнее слишком многословно).

Answer (score 4):

Лучше всего, по-моему, воспользоваться [советом @Arty OneSoul](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734381/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-url-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c/734425#comment1117364_734381) и использовать специальный модуль: [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs), чтобы избежать изобретания колеса и хождения по граблям, по которым уже прошли авторы `urllib.parse`.

"Мое колесо" - решение с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
import re

In [300]: params = url.split('#')[1]

In [301]: d = dict(re.findall(r'([^=\&]*)=([^\&]*)', params))

In [302]: d
Out[302]:
{'access_token': 'f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be27494b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146',
 'expires_in': '86400',
 'user_id': '91585260'}
```

PS всяческие проверки и обработку исключений оставляю на совести автора вопроса... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Вот можно и в одну строку на Питоне сделать:

```
params = dict(map(lambda x: x.split('=', 1), url.split('#', 1)[1].split('&')))
```

или без функциональных конструкций:

```
params = dict(x.split('=', 1) for x in url.split('#', 1)[1].split('&'))
```

выдаёт такой же результат как и программа из вопроса автора.

Comment: Хорошо выглядит :) Могу предложить вариант без функциональщины, как насчет того, чтобы добавить к вашему ответу это: `params = dict(x.split('=', 1) for x in url.split('#', 1)[1].split('&'))` ? :)

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо, добавлю такой вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Добавляю пример разбора, используя функцию [parse_qsl из urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl):

```
from urllib.parse import urldefrag, parse_qsl

url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be2749' \
      '4b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146&expires_in=86400&' \
      'user_id=91585260'
    
fragment = urldefrag(url).fragment
params = dict(parse_qsl(fragment))
print(params)
```

Консоль:

```
{
    'user_id': '91585260', 
    'access_token': 'f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be27494b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146', 
    'expires_in': '86400'
}
```

---

Функция [parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) тоже работает, но в текущем случае она возвратит словарь ключей со списком значений, который дополнительно нужно будет обработать, чтобы получить результат как в примере вопроса:

```
params = dict(parse_qs(fragment))
print(params)
```

Консоль:

```
{
    'access_token': ['f9cc1f917c3ba191cd4279be27494b6b5fba00e12ed71a6c790daf70ff9712cb8d195a875c7dea143f146'], 
    'user_id': ['91585260'], 
    'expires_in': ['86400']
}
```