# как найти filename в URL ссылке используя awk

Tags: регулярные-выражения, awk

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "https://www.myserver.com/bin/dir/Download?version=2.0&
product=program&filename=progname-Linux-x86_64.tgz&beta=yes" | awk 
'/filename=([^&]+)^\&/{print $0}'
```

Мое описание регулярки:

1. Найти filename - любые маленькие и большие буквы
2. искать все символы до знака &

Выход программы(желаемый результат): `progname-Linux-x86_64.tgz`

Не получаю ничего: толи не находит регулярку толи не печатает

Comment: Явно укажите какой желаемый результат и что вместо этого получаете. На Питоне: [`dict(parse_qsl(urlparse(input()).query))['filename']`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735214/23044).

Comment: [не всё так просто в программе *awk*](http://backreference.org/2014/01/22/pulling-out-strings/). это вам не *sed* и не *grep*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для интерпретатора *awk* программа может быть, например, такой:

```
{print gensub(/.*filename=([^&]+).*/,"\\1",1)}
```

---

пояснения:

- `gensub(что-меняем, на-что-меняем, какое-по-счёту-вхождение-меняем)`
- `\\1` — отсылка к первой группе — `([^&]+)`
- `[^x]` — любой символ кроме `x`
- `x+` — один и более символ `x`

---

для интерпретатора *sed* она будет несколько лаконичней:

```
s/.*filename=\([^&]\+\).*/\1/
```

---

пояснения:

- `s/что-меняем/на-что-меняем/`
- `\1` — отсылка к первой группе — `\([^&]\+\)`
- остальное аналогично (за исключением того, что мета-символ `+` в данном случае должен быть записан как `\+`)

Comment: /\1/ это вот что означает? Чего-то я подзабыл - остальная регулярка предельно ясна.

Comment: здесь `\1` — это второй аргумент команды *s*, т.е., «то, на что заменяем». в данном случае это отсылка к первой группе (`[^&]\+`)