# Как можно синхронизировать C++ и Python

Tags: c++, python

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой необходимостью, у меня есть код, написанный на C++ это программа со статистикой(там диаграмма и графики). И есть код на Python, который использует нейросеть для определения эмоций(tensorflow и opencv). Можно ли что-то сделать чтобы они работали вместе, то есть python работал в фоне и экспортировал статистику в C++. Я бы смог написать это все вместе. Но не получается найти скомпилированную библиотеку tensorflow для C++(для её компиляции требуется 12 ГБ ОЗУ, у меня только 8).

Comment: Посмотрите, например, на передачу данных по пайпу

Comment: @avp, а как это можно реализовать? Если есть возможность скиньте какой-нибудь гайд на русском. В гугле информации про это мало. Я в python'е не силен.

Comment: Гайдов не помню. Поищите примеры с fork/dup/exec, в которых stdin/stdout нового процесса переключаются на  пару пайпов ([man pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)) Т.о. python запускаете в дочернем процессе, он читает stdin и пишет ответы в stdout

Comment: существует множество способов связать питон и c++ код (помимо обычных IPC методов)¶ Мы живём в интересные времена, если люди могут tensorflow использовать, но не знают как связать две команды с помощью pipe¶ Если C++ заметную работу вычислительную выполняет, то из  Питона можно вызовы делать, если нет, то графопостроительством может быть удобней из Питона заниматься. [Как с помощью python сделать модуль для c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726439/23044)

Comment: @avp Это не будет компилироваться на винде же... Cygwin такое вроде и умеет, но это частный случай... Поэтому лучше уже юзать сокеты, ибо для сокетов можно найти какую-нибудь кроссплатформенную либу

Comment: Советую посмотреть в сторону TCP Server C++ и TCP Client Python. При этом использовать localhost для передачи данных. В случае с IPC все будет быстрее, но сложнее реализовать. А по TCP Socket-ам много информации в интернете.