# Запуск python скрипта в c# при поддержке ironpython. Импорт модулей

Tags: c#, python, модули, ironpython

Уважаемые знатоки! Запускаю Python скрипт следующим образом На C#:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace Telegram_py
{
    class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
       engine.ExecuteFile("J://workspace/Python/telegram_client/client.py");

    }
}
```

}

По сути методика работает. НО если в скрипте python я используй какой нибудь дополнительный импорт(в моем случае from telethon import TelegramClient). То получаю ошибку от C#:

```
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: "No module named telethon"
```

По данному пути находится только один файл client.py модуль telethon был установлен через pip и хранится в папке с python3.

Пожалуйста подскажите как правильно подвязывать модули в такой связке? Спасибо!

Comment: IronPython3 is NOT ready for use yet.

Comment: В IronPython используется питон 2.7, для третьего пока не готов.

Comment: @JaponDemon Спасибо за ответ. Все понятно =)

Comment: вы можете как внешнюю команду python3 запустить. Пример для C++ [Как с помощью python сделать модуль для c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726439/23044)

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за интересный материал. Но как я понял в процессе гугления, на С# не так много вариантов по работе с python как на C++. Такого интерпритатора точно нет в стандартных библиотеках например. Ну IronPython вот разве что

Comment: не верю, что в C# нельзя внешнюю команду запустить